# how to run multiple domains (or sub-domain) on one Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, http, routes, web-hosting

**I want to host multiple site with shared pages and functionality but don't want redirection**

> web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return "site 1";
});

Route::domain('site2.test')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return "site 2";
    });
});
```

[domain 1 preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmypP.png)

[domain 2 preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3TUr.png)

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1 site1.test
127.0.0.1 site2.test
```

> C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@media.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/multidomain/public"
    ServerName  site1.test
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@media.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/multidomain/public"
    ServerName  site2.test
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

"In order to ensure your subdomain routes are reachable, you should register subdomain routes before registering root domain routes. This will prevent root domain routes from overwriting subdomain routes which have the same URI path." ([source](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing))

You'll need to just move your `Route::domain()` to the top.